# error: entity cannot be at the top of a design, generic has no default value

Tags: vhdl, ieee

I've just started VHDL and its proving to be more difficult than I gave it credit for. At the moment im trying to get my head around the 'generic' area of operation. I've cut down my code as much as possible (this extract doesn't do anything but still produces the error) and still haven't managed to crack it. If one of you could help I would be very greatful!

thanks in advance.

```
library IEEE;

entity ALU is
    GENERIC (constant cst:integer range 15 downto 0); 
end ALU;

architecture behavioural of ALU is
    begin
End behavioural;
```

.

```
error:entity "alu" cannot be at the top of a design
alu.vhdl:6:19: generic "cst" has no default value
```

Comment: You could have removed the library clause as well. IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy para 7 "An implementation may allow, but is not required to allow, a design entity at the root of a design hierarchy to have generics and ports. If an implementation allows these top-level interface objects, it may restrict their allowed forms (that is, whether they are allowed to be interface types, subprograms, packages, or objects), and, in the case of interface objects, their allowed types and modes in an implementation-defined manner."  Implementation dependent. What tool?

Comment: Para 7 cont. "Similarly, the means by which top-level interface objects are associated with the external environment of the hierarchy are also defined by an implementation supporting top-level interface objects." That's whether or not you need default values for the generic. And what is your question?

Comment: My question is why does this very simple program produce an error. I've looked for an order to write code in and I've searched for how to give a generic a default value but I can't find anything. I think the two errors are related (I cant seem to get rid of one on its own, removing the GENERIC line removes both errors), but I have no way to tell

Comment: 6.5.6.2 Generic clauses "Generics provide a channel for information to be communicated to a block, a package, or a subprogram from its environment." 6.5.6.1 "A generic interface list consists entirely of interface constant declarations, ...." 6.5.2 Interface object declarations "interface_constant_declaration ::= [ **constant** ] identifier_list : [ **in** ] subtype_indication [ := static_expression ]", "If an interface declaration contains a “:=” symbol followed by an expression, the expression is said to be the default expression of the interface object." cst:integer range 15 downto 0) := 0;

Comment: Again, whose VHDL tool? This appears to be a ghdl bug in an outdated version from before May 15 2010 and doesn't occur in recent builds. See [ghdl-updates on Sourceforge Ticket #47](https://sourceforge.net/p/ghdl-updates/tickets/47/).  Binaries for [ghdl 0.35](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases) (Dec 2017) are available from [github](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl).

Comment: Along with identifying the tool and it's version please provide an indication of what it was doing when the error occurred (command line contents or execution log). Without these the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: As you already state in the code itself, the genetic is a constant. But you never set the value of that constant. An undefined constant is not possible, hence the error. So set the value, either in instantiation, or as default value `GENERIC (cst:integer range 15 downto 0 := 15);`

Comment: @JHBonarius thank you very much, didn't realize the generic had to be set too. Using the line you provided, all of my code now works error-free